# SQL Query contacts not in another data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, sql

Attempting to query based on a data extension called [Users], but I want to extract ALL the contacts that are also in the [Unsubscribe] data extension.

I thought it would be a simple 'NOT IN' function, but do I need to INNER JOIN, as well?

```
SELECT * FROM ENT.[Users] WHERE Email Address NOT IN ENT.[Unsubscribe]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if that's the "Email Address" field, you would have to put it in brackets [Email Address]. I suspect there is no space between them (EmailAddress).

I would use this as I have found it to work well for me when excluding fields present in another DE.

```
SELECT 

t.Email, 
t.Platform_User_Id, 
t.First_Name, 
t.Last_Name, 
t.Created_At, 
t.Last_Login_At, 
t.platform 

FROM ENT.[Users] t

LEFT JOIN ENT.[Unsubscribe] u

ON t.EmailAddress = u.EmailAddress

WHERE u.EmailAddress IS NULL
```

Comment: That works.  Only issue is that I couldn't use the '*' (select all) function as the query was using a JOIN.   Thanks @data_kid

Comment: Follow-up Question: If I were to add another DE to exclude, would it look like this?   

`SELECT` 
   ` t.Contact_Key,`
    `t.Email,`
    `t.Platform_User_Id,`
    `t.First_Name,`
    `t.Last_Name,`
    `t.Created_At,`
    `t.Last_Login_At,`
    `t.platform`
`FROM ENT.[Users] t`
`LEFT JOIN ENT.[Unsubscribe] u ON t.Email  = u.Email`
`LEFT JOIN ENT.[Suppress] m ON t.Email = m.Email_Address`
`WHERE u.Email IS NULL and m.Email_Address IS NULL`

Comment: Should work :) updated my answer apologies for the oversight